# The 'universal' proper class

Tags: set-theory

Is a 'universal' proper class ever discussed by mathematicians? If so, where and when?

What I'm talking about is, something like:

$$\{-1, 0, 1,  \frac{1}{2}, \pi, i, 2i+3j+k, \{1, 2, 3\}, \omega + 1, \omega - 1,  \mathbb{Z}, 4\hat{i}+5\hat{j}, \top, ...\}$$

A proper class containg everything, absolutely everything that is not a proper class. Integers, surreal numbers, vectors, sets, booleans, you name it.

If it is a well-defined proper class, does any branch of mathematics discuss it? If so, can you please give me some examples? (Sorry if this is a 'bad' question)

Comment: I would bet that the definition of this object would heavily depend on the axioms of set theory used, so I do not think it exists independently of those.

Comment: @opfromthestart Can you explain? Is it something like inaccessible cardinals would be part of this proper class only in some set theories?

Comment: What could there possibly be to discuss about it?  It is clearly not a set, that's as far as a discussion I would think warrants any interest.  You could discuss certain elements of it, but that would be a discussion of those specific topics and not about the class as a whole.

Comment: It also would be unlikely to have any useful properties. Classes like the surreal numbers have some use since arithmetic operations are defined, but this class would only really be closed under subsetting, which is not very useful since it does not tell anything about the objects contained in the class.

Comment: What is "everything"? The usual approach is to give the means of *constructing* anything you might want, which requires interpreting mathematical constructions in terms of some basic system (like set theory). So the class of all sets has everything in that sense. But if you want every mathematical concept to be 'primitive' in the system, I don't think that's very coherent. If Walrus spaces become all the rage next year we'll want to add them... or were they already there? It makes more sense to just have a system that's open for extension and that's how every foundational system works.

Comment: I don’t understand the flak that OP is getting here. This proper class is exactly what is called $V$ in modern set theory. It is supposed to have as members all mathematical objects (so not literally everything — no potatoes, and also not OP’s $\omega-1,$ since that’s meaningless). But it looks like this is what OP means.

Comment: @MitchellSpector if you wrote an answer about that I would probably upvote it

Comment: @MitchellSpector $\omega - 1$ is a surreal number.

Comment: @HelloWorld  Yes, I realized that after I objected to it (I was thinking of ordinal arithmetic). Anyway, that doesn’t affect the point of the comment!